Undefined references when using mingw generated library files
I need to implement some PDF generating functionality in a C++17 software so I started trying libraries.
I use mingw32 for make, compile and linking (i686-w64-mingw32 4.4.1). OS is win10. g++ version is 13.2.0.
With PDF-Writer-4.6.4 I had to use CMake to generate the MingGW Makefile which I used with mingw32-make to create the .a library files. There seemed to be no errors in these processes.
However, when I try to run the software with the newly introduced libraries I get a LOT OF undefined reference errors.
I receive the following linker errors:
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\lib\PDFWriter/libPDFWriter.a(OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp.obj):OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp:(.text$_ZN10AESencryptC1Ev[__ZN10AESencryptC1Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `aes_init'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\lib\PDFWriter/libPDFWriter.a(OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp.obj):OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp:(.text$_ZN10AESencrypt3keyEPKhi[__ZN10AESencrypt3keyEPKhi]+0x1e): undefined reference to `aes_encrypt_key'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\lib\PDFWriter/libPDFWriter.a(OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp.obj):OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp:(.text$_ZNK10AESencrypt11cbc_encryptEPKhPhiS2_[__ZNK10AESencrypt11cbc_encryptEPKhPhiS2_]+0x2c): undefined reference to `aes_cbc_encrypt'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\lib\PDFWriter/libPDFWriter.a(PNGImageHandler.cpp.obj):PNGImageHandler.cpp:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\lib\PDFWriter/libPDFWriter.a(PNGImageHandler.cpp.obj):PNGImageHandler.cpp:(.text+0x225): undefined reference to `png_get_image_width' 

Etc.. 30 more.
PDF-Writer has some dependencies which I also included and tried to link with the following link options and library directories (in addition to the rest of the program which works fine)
-lLibAesgm -lZlib -lLibTiff -lLibPng -lFreeType -lPDFWriter
-L..\lib\zlib -L..\lib\FreeType -L..\lib\LibAesgm -L..\lib\LibPng -L..\lib\PDFWriter -L..\lib\LibTiff

I can see that the issues are with OutputAESEncodeStream.cpp.obj, PNGImageHandler.cpp.obj TIFFImageHandler.cpp.obj, FreeTypeWrapper.cpp.obj etc. so basically with functions that use the related libraries' functions.
(Btw similarly I had issues when tried to build and use libharu dll.)
Can anybody help me get closer to finding what the problem here is?

Order of libraries when building matters. If you have two libraries A and B, and B depends on A, then you need to link with B first, as in -lB -lA.

Oh... and that seems to be the solution. I don't have a lot of experience with this and thought it was the other way around then I started overcomplicating things as usual. Thanks!

the reason is, in a nutshell, that the linker only looks for what is required and if it scans A first it doesnt know yet what will be needed for B

this answer in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24675715/4117728
